# can not figure out how to get the expected output by refactoring

Tags: python

How can I refactor the code by adding a check for `i["i"] not in numbers_allowed` and get the expected output, I tried adding an or condition but its not giving the expected output.

```
alphabets_allowed = {"a", "b", "c", "*"}
numbers_allowed = {"1", "2", "3", "*"}

my_list = [
    {"i": "a", "j": "alphabet"},
    {"i": "x", "j": "alphabet"},
    {"i": "1", "j": "number"},
    {"i": "8", "j": "number"},
    {"i": "*", "j": "both"}
]

def something(i):
    i["status"] = "not alphabet or number"
    print("do something", i)
    return i

for i in my_list:
    if i["i"] not in alphabets_allowed:
        something(i)
    else:
        print("ignore", i)
```

Current Output

```
ignore {'i': 'a', 'j': 'alphabet'}
do something {'i': 'x', 'j': 'alphabet', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
do something {'i': '1', 'j': 'number', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
do something {'i': '8', 'j': 'number', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
ignore {'i': '*', 'j': 'both'}
```

Expected Output

```
ignore {'i': 'a', 'j': 'alphabet'}
do something {'i': 'x', 'j': 'alphabet', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
ignore {'i': '1', 'j': 'number'}
do something {'i': '8', 'j': 'number', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
ignore {'i': '*', 'j': 'both'}
```

Wrong Output (if I change the condition to `i["i"] not in alphabets_allowed or i["i"] not in numbers_allowed`)

```
do something {'i': 'a', 'j': 'alphabet', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
do something {'i': 'x', 'j': 'alphabet', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
do something {'i': '1', 'j': 'number', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
do something {'i': '8', 'j': 'number', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
ignore {'i': '*', 'j': 'both'}
```

Comment: are you sure you didn't mean: `i["i"] not in alphabets_allowed and i["i"] not in numbers_allowed` ?

Comment: "Wrong Output (if I change the condition to `i["i"] not in alphabets_allowed or i["i"] not in numbers_allowed`)" This is because you should use `and` rather than `or` to combine the conditions. Please see the linked duplicate to understand this common logic error. Short version, in English: "Neither X nor Y" means the same thing as "Not X, and also not Y". It **does not** mean the same thing as "Either non-X, or non-Y".

Answer (score 2):

hope I'm understanding the ask correctly, but you can use `set.union` to merge both sets into one, and then use that instead. The rest of the code stays the same from what you had above.

```py
alphabets_allowed = {"a", "b", "c", "*"}
numbers_allowed = {"1", "2", "3", "*"}

all_allowed = alphabets_allowed | numbers_allowed

for i in my_list:
    if i["i"] not in all_allowed:
        ...
```

Outputs

```
ignore {'i': 'a', 'j': 'alphabet'}
do something {'i': 'x', 'j': 'alphabet', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
ignore {'i': '1', 'j': 'number'}
do something {'i': '8', 'j': 'number', 'status': 'not alphabet or number'}
ignore {'i': '*', 'j': 'both'}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have upvoted your answer, but the question linked explain the mistake

Comment: fair enough, and yeah based on the comments looks like that could indeed be the issue in this case.